# Hibernate Validator Unique Column Disallow Update Another Column

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I am using spring boot 1.4.1 with Hibernate Validator. Added custom constraint validation(UniqueRoute) on my entity like so

```
@Entity
public class Route extends BaseEntity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "route_id")
private Integer routeId;

@Column(name = "name")
@Size(max = 150)
@UniqueRoute(message="Route name already in use")
private String name;

@Column(name = "acronym")
@Size(max = 5)
@NotEmpty(message="Route acronym is required.")
private String acronym;
```

## The problem

The validation works as it should during creation of the entity, but the problem is during update, i believe a user should be able to update `acronym` even if the route exist, but in this case as during update the route already exist the user cannot update acronym

User should not be allowed to update Route name to another name that exist, but at the same time user should be able to update acronym even if name exist(unique)

## Update

I would like to get `routeId` so that i can use for validation during update.
Basically take id and check if name value changed, if not then `isValid` is true but if changed and name exist then `isValid` false otherwise true.

So i guess the problem is how to access `routeId` at `ConstraintValidator` implementation level

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Do you need to skip off the validation during the update. Please clarify your problem statement bit more so that we can help you

Comment: I think his problem is clear. Perhaps not the best answer but cant you join the two fields in an array and perform custom validation on that?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala, i don't want to skip off the validation during update, but not to update name if changed to a name that exist and also to allow acronym column to be updated even if name is not valid for update